# Virtual Hosts on WAMP causing 403 forbidden on 192.168.1.6… other aliases still work

Tags: apache, wampserver

recently modified httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf to add vhosts...

```
    #IncludeOptional "E:/wamp/vhosts/*"
Include "E:/wamp/alias/*"

NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "e:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "e:/wamp/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot E:/activeWork/projects
    ServerName projects.local
        <Directory  "E:/activeWork/projects">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot E:/activeWork/projects
    ServerName www.projects.local
        <Directory  "E:/activeWork/projects">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot E:/activeWork/projects
    ServerName api.projects.local
        <Directory  "E:/activeWork/projects">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after that when i try to load 192.168.1.6 or 127.0.0.1  ,  gives me :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

i've tried to solve it whit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276151/5753091) but not works for me

and by [recommandation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39826301/5753091) in answers i check my access.log and this is the result:

```
192.168.1.6 - - [03/Oct/2016:11:03:00 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 288
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2016:11:00:55 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 286
```

Comment: See this post it will show you how to create a [proper and complete Virtual Host definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: thanks...i read all of that  and edited my Q,but my problem is 403 error on 192.168.1.6

Comment: Show us your `httpd-vhost.conf` file please

Comment: wamp server 2.5...

Comment: all virtual hosts defined likeabove : <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

</VirtualHost>

Comment: You didnt read my link very carefully. Note what each VH definition should have included inside it!

Comment: i saw in some answers using <directory> is depricated

Comment: I dont think so, can you post a link to this deprecation information please

Comment: cant remember but search on my browser history...i made changes as u said  but still 192.168.1.6and 127.0.0.1 gives 403 error...

Comment: When you say youare using 192.168.1.6 do you mean you are trying to access the site from another PC?

Comment: it's my mistake...deprication is about allow from all and using require instead

Comment: no i try from this pc

Comment: Ok try adding `Require 192.168.1` after `Require local` on a new line

Comment: it faces problem  with restarting sevice and it remains in orange status

Comment: Sorry spelling error `Require ip 192.168.1`

Comment: when i delete all VHs 192.168.1.6 loads same page that localhost loads

Comment: Edit question and post your new `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

Comment: its all of that...projects.local works fine

Comment: You have 3 Virtual hosts all pointing at the same place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124780/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-mohammadreza-khalifeh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is to define 3 vhost point to same directory and this confused apache...finally  tnx to [riggsfolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) i fixed that...beside of this i make changes from this [guide to define VHost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990618/5753091) to have setup things in a right way

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that your wamp Installation path is inside E:
then I suggest you to check your access log and error log to collect more information.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Apache 2.4 or later on your Wampserver? If so, then replace the require rules with "Require all granted" in your vhosts, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "e:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "e:/wamp/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If it still doesn't work, check if your firewall is blocking your access.